# Magento 2 localhost wamp cron jobs

Tags: reindex, cli, indexer, wamp

I'm still getting the error on my admin page **"One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running"**
All field indexes rebuild successfully apart from **`Catalog Search`**.
I'm using **Magento 2.3.0** with **WAMP**. Additionally the **`cache:flush`** command works?

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:08
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:11
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /magento2_product_1_v1.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.2.10 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reindex,

1. Go to the Command prompt and then the root folder of your magento installation directory
2. Run the command : `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
3. Vote up & accept the answer if helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that the command I use but it errors for Catalog Search

Comment: what error comes in Catalog search?

Comment: Catalog Search indexer process unknown error: ... then a load of html as the code above about half way down